# Ortools setting constraints while solving

Tags: modeling, or-tools, integer-programming, operations-research, cp-sat

I am using CP-SAT solver from ortools
https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver

I am executing the solver with a callback object

```
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solution_agg = SolutionCollector(data, self.variables, self.products, self.vehicles)
status = solver.SearchForAllSolutions(self.model, callback=solution_agg)
```

Solution agg is supposed to filter out all solutions that have some wrong assignments, I could not model these as linear inequalities.

What I know is that generated solutions can be converged faster and the "hits" on the verifier can be made less. If I can add constraints on-the-go inside the callback.

I tried to do this inside the callback, adding a constraint to look for solutions in lesser volume than minimum volume till now.

```
self.__model.Add(volume_expression <= min_found_yet)
```

This doesn't give error, but the number of times the verifier rejected a solution is still same.

Is it possible to form constraints while solving? If not in Ortools, then any other solver which provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. The solver is stateless and read the cp_model once at the start of the solve.

What you are describing seems just a minimization property. Why don't you just minimize volume_expression?

Comment: I wanted to but SearchForAllSolutions doesn't support any minimization. I need all the feasible solutions so that function was most suitable.
Can I get all feasible solutions that minimize the expression via the Solve method of CP SAT or MIP solver?

Comment: If you solve with an objective and a solution callback, you will collect all solutions found, which may be only one. Now, if you minimize the objective, store the optimal value, then search for all solutions of a model without any objective, but with a constraint on the volume_expression, you will find all solutions close to the optimal.